# Traefik docker - requestAcceptGraceTimeout

Tags: docker, traefik

Has anyone had any experience using the ping endpoint and setting the `requestAcceptGraceTimeout` value? I have this in my toml:

```
[lifeCycle]
requestAcceptGraceTimeout = "30s"
```

However, when I instruct traefik to shutdown it only serves 503's for what appears to be around the default period of time (10s):

```
$ time docker stop traefik
traefik

real    0m12.416s
```

I’ve tried setting the value in many different ways 30, 30s, 60s, 1m, 1h but the period of time is always around the 10-12 seconds mark.

Has anyone successfully managed to set `requestAcceptGraceTimeout` and have have Traefik honour the value, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the default timeout for `docker stop` which is 10s. Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/

One way to test your `requestAcceptGraceTimeout` is to run traefik attached 
`docker run -v /traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name tt -i traefik --debug`, and then ctrl+c, you can see in the log something like, (I also have a 2s graceTimeOut)

```
time="2018-11-23T10:01:38Z" level=info msg="Waiting 30s for incoming requests to cease"
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=info msg="Stopping server gracefully"
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 2s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint traefik..."
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 2s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint https..."
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 2s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint http..."
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint https closed"
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint http closed"
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint traefik closed"
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=info msg="Server stopped"
time="2018-11-23T10:01:53Z" level=info msg="Shutting down"
```

So for the actual configuration, if you use `docker run` to launch traefik, then use `docker stop -t` to stop it, or if you use `service` inside a `compose` or `stack`, add `stop_grace_period: 30s` to the service.
`

PS The default value for `requestAcceptGraceTimeout` is 0s.

Comment: Hi @Siyu. If I understand correctly, the `requestAcceptGraceTimeout` isn't honoured if you execute a `docker stop` command against the Traefik container?

Comment: It is honoured but docker killed it before it handles the stop signal. If you use `docker stop -t {time} traefik` it works. ({time}>`requestAcceptGraceTimeout`+`graceTimeOut`)

Comment: updated my answer, I don't know what I was writing :)

Comment: Hi @Siyu, thanks for the answer and updates, all makes sense now :)